# VSCode does not show syntax errors and Error lens extension is not working

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

I tried to uninstall VSCode, cleaned up all data files, uninstalled all the extensions. None of them was working for me. please help!!!
[image]

Comment: Go to View > Output. In Output panel, select Omnisharp(I thought it was) and look at log if it says any error.

Answer (score 2):

Open workspace/folder and select the file from vscode explorer, don't open the file directly.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Type in Command palette of VS Code "Enable Error Squiggles".. This worked for me!!

Answer (score 0):

i encountered same problem, make new workspace folder and it will solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

Go to the settings and type `Error Lens: Enabled`.

Make sure you check the box.